# asp:hyperlink navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I am using `asp:hyperlink` button to open a *Terms and Condition* pop up window.
Code for the hyperlink is -

```html
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" Target="_blank"
        NavigateUrl="javascript:window.open('test.aspx');"
        ForeColor="#F58022" runat="server">Terms and Conditions
    </asp:HyperLink>
```

When I click this URL in a browser it opens up my `test.aspx` page. But along with `test.aspx` it opens up another page:

- the URL of the page is: `"javascript:window.open('test.aspx');"`
- the body of the page is: `[object]`

Can you please suggest me how to get rid of this unwanted page?

Thanks

Comment: You should wrap code tags around your hyperlink so we can see it

Answer (score 5):

Use:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" Target="_blank"
  NavigateUrl="javascript:window.open('test.aspx'); return false;"
  ForeColor="#F58022" runat="server">Terms and Conditions</asp:HyperLink>
```

The problem is that window.open returns a window object.  One purpose of the `javascript:` "protocol" was to allow javascript code to generate HTML content which is return be the expression following the protocol.  Navigation then happens to a new page containing that HTML.

In you case because you have Target="_blank" a new page is opened and the object return by your expression (the new window opened by window.open) has its toString() method called and that is what is displayed in this extra window.

**Edit**:

I've struck the code because it doesn't work.  The correct solution is provided by [silky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154152/silky).  However I'm not deleting the answer because the explanation of what is going on in the question code stands.  Hence the solution really is:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" href="#"
  onclick="window.open('test.aspx'); return false;"
  ForeColor="#F58022" runat="server">Terms and Conditions</asp:HyperLink>
```

`Target` no longer need it isn't used.  Left as HyperLink control since there may be other reasons the OP needs it as a control on the page.

Comment: It's good practice to provide the `href` and `target` properties anyway, in case JavaScript isn't enabled.

Comment: @Luke: why provide a target that is never used?  Providing href is more than a good practice, in some browsers the anchor fails to behave as an anchor without a href.

Comment: @Anthony: The `href` and `target` *will* be used if JavaScript is disabled. Having `href="test.aspx"` and `target="_blank"` should give the closest non-JS approximation of the JS behaviour. ie, opening `test.aspx` in a new window.

Comment: @Luke: I guess that depends on your audience. In many intranet (and for that matter public) sites non-JS just is a non-starter and you may was handle that way earlier. Certainly if all you are doing is window.open then you may well not bother with onclick at all

Comment: @Anthony: That's very true, but my clients usually demand that (a) users shouldn't be arbitrarily excluded from their sites for not having the "right" browser, not having JavaScript enabled etc; and (b) the sites should degrade as gracefully as possible when the user's browser isn't fully functional. The clients accept that certain things aren't possible when JS is unavailable but wouldn't be very happy if a simple link just *didn't do anything at all* with JS switched off.

Comment: @Luke: Thats fine.  The question and my answer is not addressing __your__ clients needs.  However __your__ clients are do not necessarily define what is universally "best practice".  "Best practice" can only be measured in the context of purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason why you need to use the `HyperLink` control?

You could probably just use a standard HTML link (or an [`HtmlAnchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ff86hxd.aspx) control) instead and use the client-side `onclick` event to fire your JavaScript:

```
<a id="HyperLink4" runat="server" href="test.aspx" target="_blank"
    onclick="window.open('test.aspx');return false;"
    style="color:#F58022">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it:

```
NavigateUrl="javascript:window.open('test.aspx'); return false;"
```

Better practice, however, is to put this in `OnClientClick`

```
NavigateUrl="#" OnClientClick="window.open('text.aspx'); return false"
```

-- edit:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink4" Target="_blank"
    NavigateUrl="#" OnClientClick="window.open('text.aspx'); return false"
    ForeColor="#F58022" runat="server">Terms and Conditions</asp:LinkButton >
```

Updated per comments.

Comment: I don't think the `HyperLink` control has an `OnClientClick` event/property, but the point about using the client-side `onclick` event rather than the `href` is a good one.

Comment: NavigateUrl="javascript:window.open('test.aspx'); return false;"
not working....?

Comment: Muhammad & Luke: I forgot that HyperLink doesn't have 'onclientclick'.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" Target="_blank"
        NavigateUrl="javascript:void window.open('test.aspx');"
        ForeColor="#F58022" runat="server">Terms and Conditions</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Target=_Blank`, you don't need it, the JavaScript opens a new window already...

Tip: to know why it acts differently, view source in the browser and check what the web control produces in HTML terms.